# How to add spotify framework to an custom pod

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, cocoapods, spotify

I try to add the Spotify framework to my custom cocoaPod project but i got an error :

ld: framework not found Spotify
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i added the framework in the Build Phases of project and the search Path to.
but can't build.
Any one can help me please.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following some kind of tutorial for this? This shouldn't be an issue with Cocoapods, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Make sure you clean your project first. I would remove the work you did in Build Phases, the intention of Cocoapods is to avoid adding frameworks manually as an embedded dependency.

Before a pod install, close your project. Pod install and then open up your workspace file once complete, not your xcodeproject file. Try building now. Build again with your imported pod statement. Please update if you need help further.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. but this's can't be a solution because the Spotify is an .framework and my problem's that i want to add it to a custom Pod without cocoaPods